# Need to escape a special character in a jQuery selector string

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to [the selectors docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), you must escape `[` with double backslash, etc `\\[`.

I have a selector that is created like so (assume `val` attribute is `something[4][2]` in this example).

```
var val = $(this).attr('val');           

$select.find('option[value=' +  val + ']').show();
```

Can I write a regex to escape the brackets for me?

Comment: Why not use the jQuery escapeSelector() method? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want something that works with any sort of value, try this:

```
var val = $(this).attr('val').replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]/g, "\\\\$&")
```

This works by escaping all CSS meta-characters listed on the [Selectors page of the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) with two backslashes.

Keep in mind that in your situation, there is no need to do something tricky like this. You can use the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to select all option elements with a given value without having to escape the value, as described in Mathias Bynens's answer.

Comment: FYI, your expression is missing @

Comment: I could swear I didn't see `@` on the selectors page when I wrote that, but I can't find exactly when they added it in the repository for their documentation. In any case, I am about to fix it.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case (returns "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Test \\# ") if I try to launch $(myString)

Comment: i have this strange behavior: `> cs  
< "#XMTM2NDQwNTI5Mg\\=\\=" = $7  
> $(cs)  
< Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:   #XMTM2NDQwNTI5Mg\\=\\=  
> $("#XMTM2NDQwNTI5Mg\\=\\=")  
< m [<div id="XMTM2NDQwNTI5Mg==">] (1) = $10`    then i change the variable to one escape using:`replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]/g, "\\$&")`, using variable as a selector works.

Comment: The replacement string "\\\\$&" doesn't work with jQuery 1.10. In that case, it should be "\\$&".

Answer (score 22):

CSS character escape sequences (as used in selectors) are [tricky](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes). They’re so tricky I even made [a web app that can tell you how to escape any character in CSS](http://mothereff.in/css-escapes).

It’s much simpler *and* more efficient to simply select all `option` elements and then `filter` them based on their `value` attribute value:

```
var value = this.value;
$select.find('option').filter(function() {
  return this.value == value;
}).show();
```

That way, no special escaping is needed at all.

Answer (score 7):

Late to answer but,

### jQuery 3

add the missing `""` in `'option[value="'+ val +'"]'`

```js
var val = "something[4][2]";

$("select").find('option[value="' +  val  + '"]').show();
```

```css
option{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="something[4][2]">4,2</option>
  <option value="something[1][1]">1,1</option>
</select>
```

### jQuery 3 and [`jQuery.escapeSelector()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/)

without wrapping quotes - so using your original selector `'option[value='+ val +']'`

```js
var val = "something[4][2]";           
var eSel = $.escapeSelector( val );    // something\[4\]\[2\]

$("select").find('option[value='+ eSel +']').show();
```

```css
option{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="something[4][2]">4,2</option>
  <option value="something[1][1]">1,1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

Check this out...

```
var val = $(this).attr('val').replace(/(\[|\])/g, '\\\\$1'); // something\\[4\\]\\[2\\]
```

of course, this only handles the brackets, not any other of the special characters. However, in my experience, the brackets are the only ones I use (because of PHP's handy way of handling input name attributes like these: `something[]`)

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery's FAQ](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/) has a nice solution for this that escapes all character that jQuery requires.

I like this nullsafe version of what they suggest:

```
function jqid (id) {
  return (!id) ? null : '#' + id.replace(/(:|\.|\[|\]|,|=|@)/g, '\\$1');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around the attribute value in the selector, then you only have to escape backslashes and quotes in the value:

```
var val = $(this).attr('val');

val = val.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\").replace(/"/g, '\\"');

$select.find('option[value="' +  val + '"]').show();
```

If you know that the value doesn't have any backslashes or quotes (like in your example), then you don't need to escape anything in the value, you only need the quotes in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

If the selector ends with the special char, you can't escape it using double backslashes. The work arround is to use regex : For example, if the selector id is "bonus+" then you can use:

```
$("div[id$='bonus+']")
```

It makes more sense when you have dynamic selectors.