# Escaping jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why selector works in first example, but fails in second one?
See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSpaK/6/).

```
<div id="hello[1][2]_world">&nbsp;</div>
<textarea id="console"></textarea>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

      //first example
      $('#hello\\[1\\]\\[2\\]_world').html('01234'); //everything is OK

      //second example
      var iid = 'hello[1][2]_world';    
      iid = iid.replace(/[#;&,.+*~':"!^$[\]()=>|\/]/g, "\\\\$&");
      $('#console').val(iid); //see in textarea, the same string as from first    

      $('#'+iid).html('56789'); //not working! whyyyyyyyy? :)

   });    
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first string is "actually" `'#hello\[1\]\[2\]_world'`.

What happens is that you have to escape `\`s in the first case so that the `$()` function receives `\[` and so on so that it knows that it should treat those characters as part of the id.

In the second case you're creating a string that's `hello\\\\[1\\\\]\\\\[2\\\\]_world` (as you have 4 backslashes in the replacement!) that becomes, after the backslashes have been escaped, `hello\\[1\\]\\[2\\]_world`.

You can confirm this by adding these lines at the end (look in the JS console):

```
console.log( iid );
console.log( 'hello\\[1\\]\\[2\\]_world' );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qSpaK/7/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to double escape the second one:

```
<div id="hello[1][2]_world">&nbsp;</div>
<textarea id="console"></textarea>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

      //first example
      $('#hello\\[1\\]\\[2\\]_world').html('01234'); //everything is OK

      //second example
      var iid = 'hello[1][2]_world';    
    iid = iid.replace(/[#;&,.+*~':"!^$[\]()=>|\/]/g, "\\$&");
      $('#console').val(iid); //see in textarea, the same string as from first    

      $('#'+iid).html('56789'); //not working! whyyyyyyyy? :)
   });    
</script>
```

Because really `\[` is that symbol escaped. But in your first string you have to escape the `\\` and in the second you are doing this `\\\\`. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery's FAQ](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/) has a nice solution for this that escapes all character that jQuery requires.

I like this nullsafe version of what they suggest:

```
function jqid (id) {
  return (!id) ? null : '#' + id.replace(/(:|\.|\[|\]|,)/g, '\\$1');
}
```

See answers to these questions also:

[jQuery selector value escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping/34214360#34214360)

[Need to escape a special character in a jQuery selector string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string/34214378#34214378)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid ID, and as thus you're relying on undefined behaviour. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html). Can I suggest using [data attributes](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) for storing arbitrary data instead of doing it in the ID?

Comment: I've tried to use `rel` attribute or any other, but the same problem, see http://jsfiddle.net/FJpvz/2/

Comment: You don't need to escape the brackets when they're not used as a selector, see http://jsfiddle.net/FJpvz/3/