# Error: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting the following error

Error: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: table $MainContent$gridPlans$ctl02$chkSelected
Source File: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
Line: 2

I have worked what part of the script is causing this issue but unsure how to fix it:

```
// Check Box selector
    $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function () {
        var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name"); // this line is not working
        $(column).hide();
    });

    $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
        var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
        $(column).toggle();
    });

// Manage column checkboxes that should be unchecked
function manChecks() {
    var __CS = document.getElementById('__CS');
    var cols = __CS.value; // this line also causing issues

    colManage(1, cols.indexOf('|1') != -1);
    colManage(2, cols.indexOf('|2') != -1);
    colManage(3, cols.indexOf('|3') != -1);
    colManage(5, cols.indexOf('|5') != -1);
    colManage(6, cols.indexOf('|6') != -1);
    colManage(7, cols.indexOf('|7') != -1);
    colManage(8, cols.indexOf('|8') != -1);
    colManage(9, cols.indexOf('|9') != -1);
}

function colManage(id, show) {
    document.getElementById(id).checked = show;
    var column = "table ." + id;
    if (show) {
        $(column).show();
        $('label[for=' + id + ']').addClass('checked')
    }
    else {
        $(column).hide();
        $('label[for=' + id + ']').removeClass('checked')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class selector has `$` characters in it - these need to be escaped.

[Need to escape a special character in a jQuery selector string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string)

[jQuery selector value escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping)

http://samuelsjoberg.com/archive/2009/09/escape-jquery-selectors