# jQuery selectors correct escaping

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

Followig those suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935580/error-error-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), I'm trying to escape my selector.
In chrome, no problem:

[image: Successful escaping]

But with Firefox, no success:

[image: Unsuccessful Escape tries]

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input\[id^=\"form_availabilities_\"
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: Aren't you missing a `]` at the end? **Edit:** just seen your comment about this on one of the answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you escaping anything?

```
$('input[id^=form_availabilities_]')
```

Done.

Comment: `$('input[id^="form_availabilities_"]')` is fine too (double quotes inside single quotes)

Comment: @giorgio True, but since letters and underscore make for a valid CSS identifier, quotes are not needed.

Comment: yup, just to illustrate that escaping is not needed at all when using double quotes inside singles (or other way around). OP: choose as you like!

Comment: **`(°_.)`** Shame on me, I forgot then ending '`]`'. And Chrome worked without it.

Comment: I would say the shame lies on me for not noticing and still answering your question :p