# Workaround jquery set val() behavior on SELECT when no matching value

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

If I have this select box:

```
<select id="s" name="s">
<option value="0">-</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2" selected>B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

If I try to run `$("#s").val("4")`, the selection changes to "0". (See behavior here: http://jsfiddle.net/4NwN5/) How can I make it so that if I attempt to set the select box to a value that does not exist in the select box that nothing changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// grab the selected
var s = $("#s");

// cache the current selectedIndex
var idx = s[0].selectedIndex;

// set the value
s.val("4");

// If it was set to `0`, set it back to the original index
s[0].selectedIndex = s[0].selectedIndex || idx;
```

---

And you can roll this into a plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.selectVal = function (val) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (this.nodeName === "SELECT") {
            var idx = this.selectedIndex;

            $(this).val(val);

            var newOpt = this.options[this.selectedIndex];

            if (newOpt.value !== ("" + val))
                this.selectedIndex = idx;
        }
    })
};

$("#s").selectVal(4);
```

Comment: When would s[0].selectedIndex ever be null? I'm not understanding the last line

Comment: @adam0101: It'll be `0` if it was set to the first option. Because `0` is falsey, it'll then use `idx`.

Comment: @adam0101: I updated the plugin so that it'll work when you want to set it to `0`. And FWIW, this is a very light-weight operation compared to doing a DOM selection based on the value.

Comment: I agree. Plus you're only doing one loop to set the value as opposed to a using a second loop to check for the existence of the value.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this way:

```
var toSel = 3; // Say your value is this
if($("#s option[value=" + toSel +"]").length > 0) //Check if an option exist with that value
{
    $("#s").val(toSel); //Select the value
}
```

or Just use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("#s option[value='" + toSel +"']").prop('selected', true);
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TQk6X/)

Comment: And if my option happens to have a value that is not valid in a jquery selector? Like a "["?

Comment: Is there some function to escape all special characters not valid in a jquery selector?

Comment: @adam0101 Yup we can apply regex and a utility function.. I will set up a fiddle.

Comment: @adam0101 No need to use regex see my answer update with the Demo. Just wrap the value in quotes and it will work.

Comment: @adam0101 Doesn't matter check this http://jsfiddle.net/nQwFy/. Worst case you want to apply regex check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string

Comment: @PSL was playing with your example and that made me clear out my doubt about `attr` vs `prop` +1 for that

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/fuCrQ/)***

You would want to use a custom filter before you call jquery's val

```
$.fn.valScreen = function(value){
 if( this.is("select") && this.find("option[value="+value+"]").length != 0 )
  this.val(value);//call vanilla val
 return this;//return jQuery object for chaining
};
```

You could then use it:

```
$("#s").valScreen("4");
```