# add escape characters to jquery variable on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to automatically escape characters in a jQuery variable? 
My variable looks like this:

```
var $name = $(this).prev().attr('name');
```

Things get hairy now because the name has square brackets. So when I try to do this:

```
$('input:radio[name='+$name+']').next().addClass('so_pretty');
```

javascript throws a fit because it gets confused from all the brackets.

Anyway to add those escape slashes on the fly?

Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap it in quotes, so that meta char issue doesn't happen since `[`, `]` are [metachars](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for a jquery selector.

```
$('input:radio[name="'+$name+'"]').next().addClass('so_pretty');
                    ^__       ^___
```

Comment: What happens if the name contains a `"`? This works for the presented problem, but is not a general-solution for guarding truly arbitrary attribute filters.

Comment: @user2864740 in a generic manner you can prefix them with double slash using a regex replace. Not just for `"` for all meta chars.

Comment: It seems like there ought to be some existing function that would be suitable for this :>

Comment: @user2864740 there are numerous answer on that you can look up. Here is one..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string

Comment: @user2864740 - This IS a general solution for arbitrary attribute filters, because double quotes are never allowed in an attribute token.

Comment: @Steve Double quotes *can* appear in the *value* of an attribute (which is being checked here) - the markup merely initially assigns the *value* which exists in the DOM. For instance, `<elm attr='foo"bar'>` and `<elm attr="foo&#34;bar">` are valid constructs in HTML which will result in the attribute of the DOM element having a *value* of `foo"bar` which contains a double quote character. `$(..)` only runs against the DOM, not the initial markup.

Comment: @user2864740 - I don't think you are correct... it might display as `"` when you output it (console, alert, etc.) but internally it keeps the escaped string.  This fiddle seems to confirm that PSL's solution works correctly, even with an escaped string: http://jsfiddle.net/Qc33K/

Comment: @Steve The DOM and the HTML are different. The DOM does not internally store the escaped string - it internally stores a string which needs no escaping. Escaping is for markup and human consumption. Compare with http://jsfiddle.net/Qc33K/4/ which shows an *invalid selector*. While it still magically finds the correct element, this is *blind luck and/or a quirk of the sizzle selector engine and is undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Steve Also consider that http://jsfiddle.net/Qc33K/5/ breaks sizzle for good - quite literally, *kaboom* (with an Exception thrown). On the other hand, I was expecting http://jsfiddle.net/Qc33K/11/ to work, but alas it does not work in sizzle. (Changing the `"`s to `'`s works, but then how to escape the quote, whatever it may be? A generally solution must work with any quote for any valid *value*.)