# Unable to replace a substring in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't replace the substring in a string:

```
var source = "div.col-md-4.fields:visible:eq(0) div.panel-body select:eq(0)";
var modified = source.replace(/visible:eq(0)/g, "1234");
```

I wonder why does `modified` have the same value as `source`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use **`regular expressions`** here but a simple string replace function. It will run faster and regular expressions were not made for simple tasks like this as ***they will run slightly slower*** than the simple `replace` function. Using **`regular expressions`** here is like using a nuke to open a water bottle, rather prefer simplicity, if a developer sees this code he will like the simplicity.

Change your second line to this one:

```
var modified = source.replace("visible:eq(0)", "1234");
```

Comment: +1 mate. Some of us just answered the question. You thought about the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the brackets

```
    var source = "div.col-md-4.fields:visible:eq(0) div.panel-body select:eq(0)";
    var modified = source.replace(/visible:eq\(0\)/g, "1234");

    console.log(source);
    console.log(modified);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape your chars like this **Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/cvW24/1/

hope rest help the cause `:)`

if you keen:

- [Need to escape a special character in a jQuery selector string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string)
- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

**code**

```
var source = "div.col-md-4.fields:visible:eq(0) div.panel-body select:eq(0)";
var modified = source.replace(/visible:eq\(0\)/g, "1234");

alert(modified);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your regular expression does not match the string. You need to escape the parenthesis.

```
var modified = source.replace(/visible:eq\(0\)/g, "1234");
```