# special characters in jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I have something like this :

```
$(gridId).jqGrid('resetSelection');
```

in gridId when someone enter value like "Flowsheet 1) test" got syntax error because of ")" characters.

Is there any method on JQuery to handle it?

Thanxs.

Comment: why would anyone use a jQuery selector like "Flowsheet )1 test"?

Comment: not sure of your entire context, but perhaps you should validate user input before you get to this point

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9309972/561269

Comment: You probably don't want unsanitized user input as your selector.

Comment: user enter it for title which is dynamic.

Comment: Well, do you really want them entering stuff like that? You could check the user input and if it contains special characters give them a message that informs them not to use characters like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
function TestSpecialCharacter(string) {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/.test(string) == false) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Hope this may useful