# How to select element with id containing \ in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

we have some legacy code where Html element ID's are populated dynamically from database data (I cant change the data here)
ex.   `<input type="text" id="2314/test/film/code\branch"/>`

when I get the ID  from click event like below 
`var src = window.event.srcElement;` I get `src.id= "2314/test/film/code\\branch";`

I want to use the `src.id`  to find the same element in different function `like $(_element).find("[id='" + src.id + "']").get();`

which is failing to get any ID since I see  `"\"` is replaced with `"\\"`

Please suggest me how to get around this ?

Comment: is the number unique? you can do [id^='" + src.id.replace(/\/.*/,'') + "']

Comment: number is not unique Raul

Comment: Related: [Need to escape a special character in a jQuery selector string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think jQuery lets you use `/` in a selector. It is an illegal character in an id name, but still odd that jquery seems to flat out refuse it. Since JS has no problem with that selector You can select it with JS then pass it off to the jquery wrapper.

```
$(document.getElementById('2314/test/film/code\\branch'));
```

Comment: Each \ has to be escaped, the final string must have 2 \, i.e. `'2314/test/film/code\\\\branch'`

Comment: @Musa in jquery, yes that is true, but `getElementById` does not have that same requirement (since it is native JS), so my code should work fine as written

Comment: The original ID in the HTML only has one backslash, so I believe @chiliNUT is correct.

Comment: @Musa oh I see, I thought you were saying it needed to be double escaped. Then yeah, what Matt Browne said.

Comment: if you're using getElementById then you don't need to escape the \ at all, just use one \

Comment: @Musa nope, if it was 'code\branch' it would look for whatever the escape sequence '\b' is, so you still need the double backslash

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it´s works for you

http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/vOgoLO

```
$("[id='" + str.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\')  + "']").html(str)
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct regex for backslash is '\\\\'.