# jQuery Escaping Special Characters Fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a jQuery selector to select, by an arbitrary id, an html element. The ids may contains special characters that need to be escaped. An example is `test_E///_AAAAA`

I am basically doing exactly what is going on in this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xcqegmp/) (which uses v 1.11.0, where I am using v 1.11.3 and have also tested with 2.1.3)

However, in my scaled up environment, it doesn't work. I get `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #test_E\\/\\/\\/_AAAAA`

There must be some obscure factoid about jQuery that is the difference between this working and not working. I, being a novice, have no hope of identifying it.

I notice that I am not alone though. A commentator on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string) had the same issue.

The code files are thousands of lines long, and I'm probably prohibited from posting more than a couple lines by my employer. I'm just looking for a hint, a clue, a shot in the dark about what would cause a perfectly reasonable selection string to be rejected.

Comment: "I'm just looking for a hint": don't use special characters in IDs...

Comment: the first clue would be that the element doesn't exist. but without any code, it will be tough to verify and answer.

Comment: freedomn-m. It is unavoidable. I need to have a unique and reference-able id for each DOM element, that is being populated dynamically from data. The only unique field in that data contains special characters (out of my control). WhiteHat, if a jQuery selector is not able to find a matching element, it doesn't give this error; it just has a selection size of 0. This error indicates that jQuery perceives a syntax error in the selector string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need enough backslashes :)

**ID:**
The ID of the element is `test_E\\/\\/\\/_AAAAA`. Note that backslashes don't have any special meaning in HTML, so there really are six backslashes in the ID.

**jQuery selector:** Backslashes, forward slashes, and several other characters have special meaning in jQuery selectors, so we need to escape them with a backslash. The selector therefore needs to be `#test_E\\\\\/\\\\\/\\\\\/_AAAAA`. This tells jQuery to look for an element whose ID contains `test_E`, then two backslashes, then one forward slash, and so on.

**JavaScript string literal:** To represent that selector using a JavaScript string literal, each backslash needs to be escaped. So the string literal would be `"#test_E\\\\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\\\\/_AAAAA"`.

```js
var selectionString = "#test_E\\\\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\\\\/_AAAAA";
snippet.log("actual id: " + $("p")[0].id);
snippet.log("selection string given to jQuery: " + selectionString);
snippet.log("text: " + $(selectionString).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<p id="test_E\\/\\/\\/_AAAAA">This is a test :)</p>
```

As you can see, this is extremely ugly, hard to understand, and hard to get right. I highly recommend avoiding such IDs. Another option is to use good old `document.getElementById()`, which only requires the string literal escapes:

```
$(document.getElementById('test_E\\\\/\\\\/\\\\/_AAAAA')).text()
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the fiddle doesn't work either. I have tried it in IE, Firefox and Chrome, and neither of them finds the element.

You need to escape a slash to use it in a `#` selector. If you use a backslash, you have to escape it twice, once to put it in a string, and once for the selector.

To match the id `test\A` you need the selector `#test\\A` which as a string is `"#test\\\\A"`.

To match the id `test/A` you need the selector `#test\/A` which as a string is `"#test\\/A"`.

To match the id `test_E\\/\\/\\/_AAAAA` you need the selector `#test_E\\\\\/\\\\\/\\\\\/_AAAAA` which as a string is `"#test_E\\\\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\\\\/_AAAAA"`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/463849xj/4/

Generally you should avoid unusual characters in an identity. Even if you can make it work, there is still a risk that some browser handles it differently.

#### Update:

The error message is shown with the selector unescaped, so as the error message shows the selector `#test_E\\/\\/\\/_AAAAA` it means that you actually use the string `"#test_E\\\\/\\\\/\\\\/_AAAAA"`. That leaves the slashes unescaped, which causes the syntax error.

Comment: *"You can't use a slash in a # selector"*. Yes you can, you just need some more backslashes.

Comment: @tom: Yes, you are right. Thanks. I corrected that.

Comment: It looks like the fiddle was changed. I've forked it, fixed it, and updated the link.

Comment: Apologies. Had a typo in the question. The id should have been `test_E\\\_AAAAA`

Comment: @ds390s: Then you use the selector `"#test_E\\\\\\\\\\\\_AAAAA"`.

Comment: ack. typo again `test_E///_AAAAA` which you would escape as `test_E\\/\\/\\/_AAA`, what I am currently using

Comment: @ds390s: The error message tells us that you are not using the selector that you think. See my update above.