# Question mark '?' in anchor link

Tags: html, anchor

I have jsfiddle here to illustrate my question.

https://jsfiddle.net/morettmt/psh674k7/69/

I have a nav with anchor links to blocks in the page (it's not working perfect, but that’s not the question).

This is actual being used in a WordPress site where the block and the links are created by a content manager in the backend.

My problem is the link doesn't work if it has characters like question marks '?' in it.

Why does this not work if a question mark is in the link.

```css
.block{
    background: #ddd;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] inline in the post. Completely random piece of CSS does not add any value to your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the link work with the script you would need to escape the question mark so that it works as a selector:

```
<a href="#three\?" class="js-sticky-link">Three?</a>
```

However, that makes it fail if it falls back to using the native bookmarks. For that to work you would URL encode the question mark as `%3f`:

```
<a href="#three%3f" class="js-sticky-link">Three?</a>
```

Then to make the script work it should convert the URL encoded bookmark to the escaped selector:

```
$('html, body').animate({
  'scrollTop': $($(this).attr('href').replace(/%3f/ig, '\\?')).offset().top-navHeight
}, 1000);
```

Here is a fiddle where it is implemented. I also added a link for turning the animation on and off so that you can test the fallback behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/psh674k7/83/

To make it work for any character you would use the `decodeURIComponent` method to URL decode the string, then escape any characters that needs to be escaped to make it work in the selector, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string).

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML, remove the question mark from the `href` on the `a` tag:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#one" class="js-sticky-link">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two" class="js-sticky-link">Two</a></li>
        <li><a **href="#three"** class="js-sticky-link">Three?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#four" class="js-sticky-link">Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#five" class="js-sticky-link">Five</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Also, remove the question mark from the `id` on the `div`:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="three block" **id="three"**>
        <h2>Three</h2>
    </div>
```

I have added stars round where I have changed.

Comment: It is a workaround, but sometimes it is better to go with simplicity.