# Need a javascript function that doesn't care about special characters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

I have this html string x:

```
Michelle Brook
<br></br>
The Content Mine
<br></br>
michelle@contentmine.org
```

It is taken from first lines of http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/brook/11brook.html

I would like to obtain `x.substring(0,14)=Michelle Brook`.
The problem is that before the M, there are two special characters (unicode code=10) that makes `x.substring(0,14)=Michelle Bro`.

In fact, using `x.split("")` i can see `{" "," ","M",.....}`

I wouldn't remove these characters.
I would like to make `substring` doing the right thing "keeping in mind" that special characters. How could i do? Is there a different javascript function that makes that?

Comment: I feel those 2 special characters are carriage return and new line characters. You could just [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) it before using `substring`

Comment: you may check this link, it can be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string

Comment: Use a proper html micro template and problem disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your webpage:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var arrStr = document.getElementsByClassName('blue')[0].innerHTML.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 <>]/g, '').split('<br>');
   alert(arrStr[0].trim());
}
```

```html
<p class="blue">

    Michelle Brook<br>
    The Content Mine<br>
    michelle@contentmine.org<br><br>

    Peter Murray-Rust<br>
    University of Cambridge<br>
    pm286@cam.ac.uk<br><br>

    Charles Oppenheim<br>
    City, Northampton and Robert Gordon Universities<br>
    c.oppenheim@btinternet.com

    <br><br>doi:10.1045/november14-brook
</p>
```

With the replace function you can remove any character is out of your interest:
in your case I considered you are looking for letters (uppercase, lowercase), numbers and space. You can add other characters to remove.

Answer (score 0):

y cant u alote this strimg in a functio and trim start and end of the String.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove `\n` (code 10)

> The trim() method removes whitespace from both ends of a string.
>   Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space,
>   tab, no-break space, etc.) and all the line terminator characters (LF,
>   CR, etc.).

```
x.trim().substring(0,14);
```

Or using a regex:

```
var match = x.match(/[\w ]{14}/);
console.log(match[0]);
```