# javascript keyup not working with "array"

Tags: javascript, keyup

I have this small function:

```
$('#part[en]').keyup(function(){
    //console.log($(this).val());
    $slug = slugify($(this).val());
    $('#part_slug').val($slug);
})
```

It doesn't work. After some try and error, I understood the problem is with the ID (part[en]). If I change it to "part" (and change it in HTML too) it works.
My problem is that I need to use part[en] since I need to work them as an array with PHP.

How can I achieve this?
Also, I need to do the exact same thing with 2 ID's (keyup or change). There's any way to make something link

```
part[en].keyup OR part2[en].keyup
```

Or I need to create two seperate functions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `[en]` in your id?

Comment: It's the array created. I have some inputs each one in their own language (like part[en], part[es]. Then I work them as an array, for each [xx] in part.

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique, if you want to associate multiple elements, use classes instead of IDs.

Comment: and the ID is unique. part[en] is different from part[es] . My problem is that JS seems not to accept the [en] part. And I need to validate that... :\

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to escape a special character in a jQuery selector string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string)

Comment: The problem with the code is that `[]` are special tokens to trigger attribute selector. You need to escape those.

Comment: I see, in that case, use camel case notation `partEn` or dashes `part_en` because `[` and `]` are not accepted characters for IDs.

Comment: You don't need array notation to set the same function as a callback for an event for multiple elements, you can specify a selector for multiple elements (eg: `$("part_en, part_es")`).