# How can I escape some characters in a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, selector

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: `#skill-game-list option[value='aprendre à compter jusqu'à 5']`

There is error sended by Chrome when i try to select an element with a specific value.
this value is loaded from DB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to escape a special character in a jQuery selector string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string)

Comment: try the `escapeSelector` $.escapeSelector("'aprendre à compter jusqu'à 5'")

Comment: The need to escape the `'` within the value, which you can do with ```\\```: `#skill-game-list option[value='aprendre à compter jusqu\\'à 5']`