# Javascript - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Edit:**
I think the issue is not with concatenation itself but the special character in the id of the element I am trying to select.

**Original:**

I am having problem with concatenating two strings. It seems the problem is because one of the strings contains '!'. Sadly, I have no control over what that string can contain. I tried using '+' to make single string of the two before I tried `concat()`. But the error remains the same.

The relevant code is `$('#id_online_status_'.concat(msg.id)).removeClass('text-success').addClass('text-muted');`

Error is this:

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #id_online_status_specific.YqzvRnpU!OPMxkuoFQILY`

Please help with fixing this. I am not much familiar with JS in general.

Comment: The concat is fine but you're trying to select an id with an `!` character which is illegal. Here's a [mcve] of your problem: `$("#!")`.

Comment: `const $status = $("[id='id_online_status_"+msg.id+'"]")`

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string

Comment: This should help you: $('#id_online_status_'.concat(msg.id.replace(/([!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~])/g, '\\$1'))).removeClass('text-success').addClass('text-muted');

Comment: You likely also can use this: `$("[id$='"+msg.id+"']")`

Answer (score 0):

> change your code like this and try

```
$('#id_online_status_'+msg.id).removeClass('text-success').addClass('text-muted');
```

> remove 'concat' and try with (+)

Comment: The issue is special char in the selector

Comment: _I tried using '+' to make single string of the two before I tried concat(). But the error remains the same._

Comment: yes. but we can resolve the issue remove concat() and replace it with + mark

Comment: send me, how you tried it with + mark ??

Comment: It is not my question. The problem is ? `id="id_online_status_123!456"` cannot be selected using a selector like yours

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786538/need-to-escape-a-special-character-in-a-jquery-selector-string

Comment: I used `'#id_online_status_'+msg.id` before. But @mplungjan is right. The issue seems to be with element id having special character in it. I will edit the pots.

Comment: I think this explains the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: mmm yes. the error comes with an Exclamation mark. don't use the unsafe characters for best practices.  Thanks @Newbie

Comment: @Newbie Your link is already used to close this question as dupe

Comment: @KavinduChathuranga If you delete your answer, OP can delete the question

Comment: I think the discussion will be useful for another developer.

Comment: I ended up using `attr("data-status-userid", user.id);` to do what I wanted to do with elements ID. This resolve my original issue. In the end I wanted uniqueness of the elements. So setting attr gives me that. Thank you all who tried to help. I appreciate it.